# Keep zoomable image in center of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, zooming

In my iPhone app, I need to provide the user with an ability to zoom/pan a large-ish image on the screen.  This is quite simple: I use `UIScrollView`, set max/min scale factors and zooming/panning works as expected.  Here's where things get interesting.  The image is a dynamic one, received from a server.  It can have any dimensions.  When the image first loads, it's scaled down (if needed) to fit completely into the `UIScrollView` and is centered in the scroll view - the screenshot is below:

[image]

Because the proportions of the image are different from those of the scroll view, there's white space added above and below the image so that the image is centered.  However when I start zooming the image, the actual image becomes large enough to fill the whole of the scrollview viewport, therefore white paddings at top/bottom are not needed anymore, however they remain there, as can be seen from this screenshot:

[image]

I believe this is due to the fact that the `UIImageView` containing the image is automatically sized to fill the whole of `UIScrollView` and when zoomed, it just grows proportionally.  It has scale mode set to `Aspect Fit`.  `UIScrollView`'s delegate `viewForZoomingInScrollView` simply returns the image view.

I attempted to recalculate and re-set `UIScrollView`, `contentSize` and image view's size in `scrollViewDidEndZooming` method:

```
CGSize imgViewSize = imageView.frame.size;
CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;

CGSize realImgSize;
if(imageSize.width / imageSize.height > imgViewSize.width / imgViewSize.height) {
    realImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgViewSize.width, imgViewSize.width / imageSize.width * imageSize.height);
}
else {
    realImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgViewSize.height / imageSize.height * imageSize.width, imgViewSize.height);
}
scrollView.contentSize = realImgSize;

CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
fr.size = realImgSize;
imageView.frame = fr;
```

However this was only making things worse (with bounds still being there but panning not working in the vertical direction).

Is there any way to automatically reduce that whitespace as it becomes unneeded and then increment again during zoom-in?  I suspect the work will need to be done in `scrollViewDidEndZooming`, but I'm not too sure what that code needs to be.

Comment: Acton Dog, you say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I got it.  The solution is to use the `scrollViewDidEndZooming` method of the delegate and in that method set `contentInset` based on the size of the image.  Here's what the method looks like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    CGSize imgViewSize = imageView.frame.size;
    CGSize imageSize = imageView.image.size;

    CGSize realImgSize;
    if(imageSize.width / imageSize.height > imgViewSize.width / imgViewSize.height) {
        realImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgViewSize.width, imgViewSize.width / imageSize.width * imageSize.height);
    }
    else {
        realImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgViewSize.height / imageSize.height * imageSize.width, imgViewSize.height);
    }

    CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    fr.size = realImgSize;
    imageView.frame = fr;

    CGSize scrSize = scrollView.frame.size;
    float offx = (scrSize.width > realImgSize.width ? (scrSize.width - realImgSize.width) / 2 : 0);
    float offy = (scrSize.height > realImgSize.height ? (scrSize.height - realImgSize.height) / 2 : 0);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offy, offx, offy, offx);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Note that I'm using animation on setting the inset, otherwise the image jumps inside the scrollview when the insets are added.  With animation it slides to the center.  I'm using `UIView` `beginAnimation` and `commitAnimation` instead of animation block, because I need to have the app run on iphone 3.

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I tried your solution and it doesn't work for me.  Any other advice?

Answer (score 18):

Awesome!

Thanks for the code :)

Just thought I'd add to this as I changed it slightly to improve the behaviour.

```
// make the change during scrollViewDidScroll instead of didEndScrolling...
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGSize imgViewSize = self.imageView.frame.size;
    CGSize imageSize = self.imageView.image.size;

    CGSize realImgSize;
    if(imageSize.width / imageSize.height > imgViewSize.width / imgViewSize.height) {
        realImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgViewSize.width, imgViewSize.width / imageSize.width * imageSize.height);
    }
    else {
        realImgSize = CGSizeMake(imgViewSize.height / imageSize.height * imageSize.width, imgViewSize.height);
    }

    CGRect fr = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    fr.size = realImgSize;
    self.imageView.frame = fr;

    CGSize scrSize = scrollView.frame.size;
    float offx = (scrSize.width > realImgSize.width ? (scrSize.width - realImgSize.width) / 2 : 0);
    float offy = (scrSize.height > realImgSize.height ? (scrSize.height - realImgSize.height) / 2 : 0);

    // don't animate the change.
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offy, offx, offy, offx);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Here's my solution that works universally with any tab bar or navigation bar combination or w/o both, translucent or not.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
  // The scroll view has zoomed, so you need to re-center the contents
  CGSize scrollViewSize = [self scrollViewVisibleSize];
  // First assume that image center coincides with the contents box center.
  // This is correct when the image is bigger than scrollView due to zoom
  CGPoint imageCenter = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width/2.0,
                                    self.scrollView.contentSize.height/2.0);

  CGPoint scrollViewCenter = [self scrollViewCenter];

  //if image is smaller than the scrollView visible size - fix the image center accordingly
  if (self.scrollView.contentSize.width < scrollViewSize.width) {
    imageCenter.x = scrollViewCenter.x;
  }

  if (self.scrollView.contentSize.height < scrollViewSize.height) {
    imageCenter.y = scrollViewCenter.y;
  }

  self.imageView.center = imageCenter;
}


//return the scroll view center
- (CGPoint)scrollViewCenter {
  CGSize scrollViewSize = [self scrollViewVisibleSize];
  return CGPointMake(scrollViewSize.width/2.0, scrollViewSize.height/2.0);
}


// Return scrollview size without the area overlapping with tab and nav bar.
- (CGSize) scrollViewVisibleSize {
  UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.scrollView.contentInset;
  CGSize scrollViewSize = CGRectStandardize(self.scrollView.bounds).size;
  CGFloat width = scrollViewSize.width - contentInset.left - contentInset.right;
  CGFloat height = scrollViewSize.height - contentInset.top - contentInset.bottom;
  return CGSizeMake(width, height);
}
```

**Swift 5:**

```
public func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    centerScrollViewContents()
}

private var scrollViewVisibleSize: CGSize {
    let contentInset = scrollView.contentInset
    let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.standardized.size
    let width = scrollViewSize.width - contentInset.left - contentInset.right
    let height = scrollViewSize.height - contentInset.top - contentInset.bottom
    return CGSize(width:width, height:height)
}

private var scrollViewCenter: CGPoint {
    let scrollViewSize = self.scrollViewVisibleSize()
    return CGPoint(x: scrollViewSize.width / 2.0,
                   y: scrollViewSize.height / 2.0)
}

private func centerScrollViewContents() {
    guard let image = imageView.image else {
        return
    }

    let imgViewSize = imageView.frame.size
    let imageSize = image.size

    var realImgSize: CGSize
    if imageSize.width / imageSize.height > imgViewSize.width / imgViewSize.height {
        realImgSize = CGSize(width: imgViewSize.width,height: imgViewSize.width / imageSize.width * imageSize.height)
    } else {
        realImgSize = CGSize(width: imgViewSize.height / imageSize.height * imageSize.width, height: imgViewSize.height)
    }

    var frame = CGRect.zero
    frame.size = realImgSize
    imageView.frame = frame

    let screenSize  = scrollView.frame.size
    let offx = screenSize.width > realImgSize.width ? (screenSize.width - realImgSize.width) / 2 : 0
    let offy = screenSize.height > realImgSize.height ? (screenSize.height - realImgSize.height) / 2 : 0
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: offy,
                                           left: offx,
                                           bottom: offy,
                                           right: offx)

    // The scroll view has zoomed, so you need to re-center the contents
    let scrollViewSize = scrollViewVisibleSize

    // First assume that image center coincides with the contents box center.
    // This is correct when the image is bigger than scrollView due to zoom
    var imageCenter = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width / 2.0,
                              y: scrollView.contentSize.height / 2.0)

    let center = scrollViewCenter

    //if image is smaller than the scrollView visible size - fix the image center accordingly
    if scrollView.contentSize.width < scrollViewSize.width {
        imageCenter.x = center.x
    }

    if scrollView.contentSize.height < scrollViewSize.height {
        imageCenter.y = center.y
    }

    imageView.center = imageCenter
}
```

Why it's better than anything else I could find on SO so far:

1. It doesn't read or modify the UIView frame property of the image view since a zoomed image view has a transform applied to it. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame?language=objc) what Apple says on how to move or adjust a view size when a non identity transform is applied.
2. Starting iOS 7 where translucency for bars was introduced the system will auto adjust the scroll view size, scroll content insets and scroll indicators offsets. Thus you should not modify these in your code as well.

FYI: 
There're check boxes for toggling this behavior (which is set by default) in the Xcode interface builder. You can find it in the view controller attributes:

[image: automatic scroll view adjustments]

The full view controller's source code is published [here](https://github.com/giosad/ImageScroll/blob/master/ImageScroll/ImageScroll/ViewController.m).

Also you can download the [whole Xcode project](https://github.com/giosad/ImageScroll/archive/master.zip) to see the scroll view constraints setup and play around with 3 different presets in the storyboard by moving the initial controller pointer to any the following paths:

1. View with both translucent tab and nav bars.
2. View with both opaque tab and nav bars.
3. View with no bars at all.

Every option works correctly with the same VC implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, genk! I was struggling with the problem for a long time. If you were in India, I would have sent chocolates for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the swift 3 version of [Genk's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135933) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35680604/2398886)

```
    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
        let imgViewSize:CGSize! = self.imageView.frame.size;
        let imageSize:CGSize! = self.imageView.image?.size;
        var realImgSize : CGSize;
        if(imageSize.width / imageSize.height > imgViewSize.width / imgViewSize.height) {
            realImgSize = CGSize(width: imgViewSize.width,height: imgViewSize.width / imageSize.width * imageSize.height);
        }
        else {
            realImgSize = CGSize(width: imgViewSize.height / imageSize.height * imageSize.width, height: imgViewSize.height);
        }
        var fr:CGRect = CGRect.zero
        fr.size = realImgSize;
        self.imageView.frame = fr;

        let scrSize:CGSize = scrollView.frame.size;
        let offx:CGFloat = (scrSize.width > realImgSize.width ? (scrSize.width - realImgSize.width) / 2 : 0);
        let offy:CGFloat = (scrSize.height > realImgSize.height ? (scrSize.height - realImgSize.height) / 2 : 0);
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(offy, offx, offy, offx);

        // The scroll view has zoomed, so you need to re-center the contents
        let scrollViewSize:CGSize = self.scrollViewVisibleSize();

        // First assume that image center coincides with the contents box center.
        // This is correct when the image is bigger than scrollView due to zoom
        var imageCenter:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.scrollView.contentSize.width/2.0, y:
                                          self.scrollView.contentSize.height/2.0);

        let scrollViewCenter:CGPoint = self.scrollViewCenter()

        //if image is smaller than the scrollView visible size - fix the image center accordingly
        if (self.scrollView.contentSize.width < scrollViewSize.width) {
            imageCenter.x = scrollViewCenter.x;
        }

        if (self.scrollView.contentSize.height < scrollViewSize.height) {
            imageCenter.y = scrollViewCenter.y;
        }

        self.imageView.center = imageCenter;

    }
    //return the scroll view center
    func scrollViewCenter() -> CGPoint {
        let scrollViewSize:CGSize = self.scrollViewVisibleSize()
        return CGPoint(x: scrollViewSize.width/2.0, y: scrollViewSize.height/2.0);
    }
    // Return scrollview size without the area overlapping with tab and nav bar.
    func scrollViewVisibleSize() -> CGSize{

        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset;
        let scrollViewSize:CGSize = self.scrollView.bounds.standardized.size;
        let width:CGFloat = scrollViewSize.width - contentInset.left - contentInset.right;
        let height:CGFloat = scrollViewSize.height - contentInset.top - contentInset.bottom;
        return CGSize(width:width, height:height);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an extension tested on **Swift 3.1**. Just create a separate ***.swift** file and paste the code below:

```
import UIKit

extension UIScrollView {

    func applyZoomToImageView() {
        guard let imageView = delegate?.viewForZooming?(in: self) as? UIImageView else { return }
        guard let image = imageView.image else { return }
        guard imageView.frame.size.valid && image.size.valid else { return }
        let size = image.size ~> imageView.frame.size
        imageView.frame.size = size
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(
            x: self.frame.size.width ~> size.width,
            y: self.frame.size.height ~> size.height
        )
        imageView.center = self.contentCenter
        if self.contentSize.width < self.visibleSize.width {
            imageView.center.x = self.visibleSize.center.x
        }
        if self.contentSize.height < self.visibleSize.height {
            imageView.center.y = self.visibleSize.center.y
        }
    }

    private var contentCenter: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: contentSize.width / 2, y: contentSize.height / 2)
    }

    private var visibleSize: CGSize {
        let size: CGSize = bounds.standardized.size
        return CGSize(
            width:  size.width - contentInset.left - contentInset.right,
            height: size.height - contentInset.top - contentInset.bottom
        )
    }
}

fileprivate extension CGFloat {

    static func ~>(lhs: CGFloat, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return lhs > rhs ? (lhs - rhs) / 2 : 0.0
    }
}

fileprivate extension UIEdgeInsets {

    init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        self.bottom = y
        self.left = x
        self.right = x
        self.top = y
    }
}

fileprivate extension CGSize {

    var valid: Bool {
        return width > 0 && height > 0
    }

    var center: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: width / 2, y: height / 2)
    }

    static func ~>(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        switch lhs > rhs {
        case true:
            return CGSize(width: rhs.width, height: rhs.width / lhs.width * lhs.height)
        default:
            return CGSize(width: rhs.height / lhs.height * lhs.width, height: rhs.height)
        }
    }

    static func >(lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGSize) -> Bool {
        return lhs.width / lhs.height > rhs.width / rhs.height
    }
}
```

The way to use:

```
extension YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW_DELEGATE: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
        scrollView.applyZoomToImageView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Analogous to different answers based on setting `contentInset`, but shorter. Remember about setting `scrollView.delegate`.

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetX = max((scrollView.bounds.size.width - scrollView.contentSize.width) * 0.5, 0.0)
    let offsetY = max((scrollView.bounds.size.height - scrollView.contentSize.height) * 0.5, 0.0)

    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: offsetY, left: offsetX, bottom: offsetY, right: offsetX);
}
```

If you want to take a look on a few different strategies, here is a place worth to look: [github](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCenteredScrollView) & [post](https://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/how-to-center-uiscrollview/).

Comment: this is unreal 