# How to do zoom in, out in UIScrollView using UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

Mainscroll is scrollview which was added into another internal UIView and i have UISlider to change internal view scale.

But, `MainScroll.setZoomScale(CGFloat(sender.value), animated: true)` this line is not work.

==> Here is my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    MainScroll.maximumZoomScale = 1
    MainScroll.minimumZoomScale = 10

    MainScroll.delegate = self

    MainScroll.zoomScale = 5
}

@IBAction func Scrolling(_ sender: UISlider) {

    MainScroll.setZoomScale(CGFloat(sender.value), animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example for getting a `UIScrollView` to zoom.

The key is that you have to implement `func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?` and return a view (that is inside your scrollView) that is to be scaled (think of it like your 'document' or 'canvas' view).

Also, notice that zoom is working for the default pinch gestures on the scrollView as well.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    // Assume that outlets exist on a storyboard
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var canvas: UIView! // A view that is added in the scrollView
    @IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!

    let minScale: CGFloat     = 1
    let maxScale: CGFloat     = 10
    let initialScale: CGFloat = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate         = self

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = maxScale
        scrollView.zoomScale        = initialScale

        slider.minimumValue         = Float(minScale)
        slider.maximumValue         = Float(maxScale)
        slider.value                = Float(initialScale)
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return canvas
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        scrollView.zoomScale = CGFloat(sender.value)
    }

}
```

Comment: still not working. Can you explain storyboard constraint your applying ? @Alladinian

Comment: @DigvijayGida I have thoroughly tested this and it's working ok on my side. The storyboard has a minimal setup as well, just a scrollView with a subview (the `canvas` in my example). Did you implement `viewForZooming`?

Comment: Sorry for it's work. Thank you so much for help. Can you help me one more ? Here scale in, out superview center    @Alladinian

Comment: @DigvijayGida I'm glad that helped you. In case you got any other issues please consider opening a new question with your current code. Thanks

Comment: If possible please reply. Just i need scale in, out in center. I can not ask more question at a time because here is per day ask question limit. @Alladinian

Comment: You can search for similar questions. [Here is one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069571/keep-zoomable-image-in-center-of-uiscrollview)

Comment: Thanks bro, now i can do this task.